# Rails, Javascript & Turbolinks - function not available

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a rails app and I am trying to organize my javascript into page specific javascript files and only load it if the page requires it.
I use a 2nd manifest file to load page-specific javascript for my "goal_designer" page.

If I do a 'view page source' on my goal_designer page (after I follow a link t it, not reload it)  I confirm that the js file has been added:

```
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/files/goal_designer.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/goal_designer_bundle.js?body=1"></script>
```

However, if I try to use a function that is within this file it does not work.
If I reload the page it works fine and the function is available to use.

In my app/assets/files/goal_designer.js I have:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
  hello_there_1();
});  

$(document).on('page:load', function(){
  hello_there_1();
});  

function hello_there_1() {
  alert("hello_there_1");     
}
```

hello_there_1 only gets triggered if I reload the page, not if I navigate to it.
My understanding was that the goal_designer.js should be available as it has been added to  on this page and the hello_there_1() function should be available but this does not seem to be the case.
So, once the page:loads then the function should trigger.

Another thing - if I look at the assets list in the Chrome debugger (Sources) the goal_designer.js only appears in the list if I reload the page, not if I navigate to it (even though it is in the 'page source' ok).

1. I am in development mode so I thought all js would be preloaded or available to be referenced.  Is this correct?
2. If I click into a page, and the page-specific js gets added to the head, how can I bind an addEventListener to an object on the page from within this newly loaded file?

FYI - other info - I think I am doing this bit right.
I use this code in my goal_designer.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'goal_designer_bundle' %>
<% end %>
```

And this in my application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= yield :head %>
```

In my app/assets/javascripts I have a manifest file, goal_designer_bundle.js, which contains:

```
//= require ./files/goal_designer
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, Turbolinks doesn't update the `<head>` section, only the body. The idea is that your JS and CSS is requested once on initial page load and subsequent requests avoid this by using AJAX and simply replacing the body. Thus, with the way Turbolinks is designed to work, your `content_for :head` block won't work.

Philosophically your approach is very different from how Turbolinks works so if you plan on using it I would just disable Turbolinks.

Comment: Thanks Bart. I've read so many blogs on this I am clearly mixing up the advice.   I would prefer to use the Turbolinks approach so is there a way to have page-specific js or is that the opposite philosophy also?   I guess I can list all js files in the application.js for turbolinks managment and then use a controller-action identifier within the file to activate the code on a page:change?